# Specific pathing to find XML elements using minidom in Python

Tags: python, xml, dom

As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python/1912516#1912516), I am using [`xml.dom.minidom`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) to do some very basic XML traversing, read-only.

What confuses me is why its `getElementsByTagName` is finding nodes several hierarchy levels deep without explicitly supplying it with their exact path.

XML:

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item name="item1"></item>
        <item name="item2"></item>
        <item name="item3"></item>
        <item name="item4"></item>
    </items>
    <secondSetOfItems>
        <item name="item5"></item>
        <item name="item6"></item>
        <item name="item7"></item>
        <item name="item8"></item>
    </secondSetOfItems>
</data>
```

Python code:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('sampleXML.xml')
items = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item') 

for item in items:
    print item.attributes['name'].value
```

Prints:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8
```

What bothers me is that it implicitly finds tags named `item` under both `data->items` as well as `data->secondSetOfItems`.

How do I make it follow an explicit path and only extract items under one of the two categories?  E.g. under `data->secondSetOfItems`:

```
item5
item6
item7
item8
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get items from a specific category, you can do so by grabbing the parent element first.

For example:

**Code**:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('sampleXML.xml')
#Grab the first occurence of the "secondSetOfItems" element
second_items = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("secondSetOfItems")[0]
item_list = second_items.getElementsByTagName("item")

for item in item_list:
    print item.attributes['name'].value
```

**Output**:

```
item5
item6
item7
item8
```

Comment: great thanks.  one more question:  say i had a value inside the item tag `<item name="item8">XYZ</item>`.  how would i read the XYZ ?  i tried `item.nodeValue` to no avail

Comment: nvrmnd, it should be `item.childNodes[0].nodeValue`

Answer (score 1):

this is the declared behavior of [getElementsByTagName](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Document.getElementsByTagName)

> Search for all descendants (direct children, children’s children, etc.) with a particular element type name.

some wrote a "filter" on it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598016/41576)

seem to me that minidom is too simple, consider using lxml xpath:

```
tree.xpath('//secondSetOfItems/item/@name')
```

or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) findAll:

```
data.secondSetOfItems.item.findAll('name')
```